# Joomla plugin database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, joomla3.0

I am working on a plugin that handles logs, as such it needs its own database table. However doing the typical manifest does not seem to work and is causing errors. Not sure where I may be going wrong as searching this issue has yielded no results.

```
<install>
   <sql>
      <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/mysql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
   </sql>
</install>
```

I tested the SQL in phpmyadmin and it works fine. All it needs to do is create a simple table with 4 columns.

Comment: Can you provide your SQL code. If you want, I will be more than happy to test you plugin.

Comment: The SQL was working, and through changing it to an answer below it changed to an installer rather then an SQL file. Witch works for the simple idea of adding a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes sense to do it: if you create a table, you need to provide some management features, at least view and delete / empty, so you typically would want to write a component for that.  You could then build a package and distribute them in one file.

If you really want to try, another option could be to create the table in a postflight event, you can write a function to be invoked after installation (typically used to enable the plugin) and create the table there.

Comment: In this case its just a log, it is with a component but an add on. So it needs to manage its own table. There is no need to view/delete them via the admin at this point. I will see about an installer script for it, although it is kind of strange that the install sql stuff works, just has an error for plugins if it is not supported. It being supported would make this process easy.

Comment: Lots of plugins manage tables, the profile plugin is a good example.